# Making manifest file in java by command prompt

Tags: java, command-line, jar, manifest

I'm trying to make a 'jar file' and run it by first making manifest file.
as I enter jar command in command prompt and using all explanation, this is what I think is sensible:

```
>md build\classes          ----first I made a directory for my class files--

>javac -d build\classes src\*.java     ----then compile java files from src folder to classes folder----

>javadoc src\*.java -d doc    ----make documentation----

>jar -cfm my.jar m.txt -C build\classes    ----I want to make a my.jar file and put the manifest contents from .class in build \classes to m.txt but I don't know what's wrong that I can't make a manifest file as m----

java -jar my.jar
```

I mentioned above the problem in making manifest file so that I can run .jar file.
what's wrong with my code for making the manifest file?

this is what it print when I run the command for making manifest file:

> Usage: jar {ctxui}[vfmn0Me] [jar-file] [manifest-file] [entry-point] [-C dir] files ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add a . at the end of your jar.exe command, or whatever you wish to include from the build\classes directory. The -C command allows you to change directory, but you then need to specify what to include from that directory thereafter.

So...

```
jar -cfm my.jar m.txt -C build\classes .
```

I'm assuming that your manifest file is already created. If not, then you can echo via the command line and output it to a file. For example...

```
echo Main-Class: path.to.YourClass > MANIFEST.MF (or m.txt)
```

Comment: Thanks, I put '.' at the and of the command, and I should mention that there is just one .class in the path build\classes and I want to get the manifest file from the class file(which is generated by compile a java file earlier) I did the same thing that you said but this is what it said: "java.io.FileNotFoundException: m.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)"     I even made the .txt file manually but the m.txt file was empty, what I didi wrong?